# How to change a boolean from another script C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean

I have 2 script, playerMachanics and enemyBehavior. My enemyBehavior has a boolean that when the boolean is true it moves away from the player. Instead i'm getting the error: "object reference not set to an instance of an object".

I'm sure it means the script can't find the component but i can't quite figure out what's wrong.

```cs
public class enemyBehavior : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool evade = false;
    public GameObject Player;
    public float movementSpeed = 4;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.LookAt(Player.transform);
        transform.position += transform.forward * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        if (evade == true)
        {
            movementSpeed = -4;
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
public class playerMechanics : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {

        enemyBehavior evade = gameObject.GetComponent<enemyBehavior>();
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "coin")
        {
            Destroy(collision.gameObject);
            enemyBehavior script = GetComponent<enemyBehavior>();
            script.evade = script.evade == true;
        }
    }
}
```

I expected that the movementSpeed would go to -4 but now i'm just getting an error.

Comment: `script.evade = script.evade == true;` does not do anything. Are you trying to reverse the value? If so, change `true` to `false`, or just do: `script.evade = !script.evade;`

Comment: My main issue is the error: "object reference not set to an instance of an object". I can't even do anything while that's there...

Comment: @RufusL it's             script.evade = script.evade == false;

Comment: So that means `script` is `null`. From [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html): *"Returns the component of Type type if the game object has one attached, null if it doesn't."*. Also, it looks like this line isn't needed: `enemyBehavior evade = gameObject.GetComponent<enemyBehavior>();`

Comment: @RufusL yes, that line wasn't needed. I removed it but i still don't understand what i have to do to fix the evade. I changed it to: script.evade = !script.evade; but i'm still getting the error

Comment: Test for null first? `if (script != null) { script.evade = !script.evade; }`

Comment: @RufusL can confirm it was a null, yes

Answer (score 0):

Calling getComponent by itself will look for the component attached to the parent object of the script, which is the player in this case I think. So it will always return null.

Add

```
Public GameObject enemy;
```

to the playerMechanics class and then go into the designer and drag the game object that has the enemyBehavior script attached into it. There are several problems with the onCollisionEnter method. Something like this

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.name == "coin")
    {
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);
        enemyBehavior script = enemy.GetComponent<enemyBehavior>();
        script.evade = false;
    }
}
```

should get you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Is the enemy behavior on the player object? See here

```
enemyBehavior evade = gameObject.GetComponent<enemyBehavior>();
```

and here

```
enemyBehavior script = GetComponent<enemyBehavior>();
```

You need to implement a way to track which enemy instance you are grabbing. Do this by making a variable to hold the enemy script, or by using a singleton on the enemy script (if there is one enemy).
Variable:

```
public enemyBehaviour enemy;
```

Singleton:
(enemyBehaviour)

```
public static enemyBehaviour instance = null;
private static readonly object padLock = new object();

void Awake(){
  lock(padLock){
    if(instance == null)
      instance = this;
  }
}
```

(player)

```
enemyBehaviour.instance.evade = false;
```

Look up singletons if you want to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm right, I think your game mechanics works like this: The player's objective is to collect coins. When they collect one, the enemy near it will come and evade the player.

If that's the case, you should use this:

```
public class enemyBehavior : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public bool evade = false;
        public GameObject Player;
        public float movementSpeed = 4;

        void Start()
        {
            Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
        }
        void Update()
        {
            transform.LookAt(Player.transform);
            transform.position += transform.forward * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

            if (evade)
            {
                movementSpeed = -4;
            }
        }
    }

    public class playerMechanics : MonoBehaviour
    {

        [SerializeField] enemyBehvaior enemy;

        void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
        {
            if (collision.collider.name == "coin")
            {
                Destroy(collision.collider.gameObject);
                enemy.evade = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

In your code, you wrote 'collision.gameObject.' This refers to the object the script is attached to. If you want to reference to the object that we hit, use 'collision.collider'.

'[SerializeField]' is a unity [attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/), which is used to make a field show up in the inspector without making it public.

Just a heads up, if you're using 2D, make sure the method is signatured 'OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)'.

I hope I answered your question. :)